# How to Auto capture without any user interface ("Button") inside an overlay using camera2 by google?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using google camera2 api and was able to successfully make a GREEN rectangular overlay using surface view. Now the challenge is to capture a preview with out button only when the object comes inside rectangular overlay after touching the four corners of the the overlay. Tried alot but still no success. The whole code is from google sample camera2 so presenting only the part where changes were made.
(https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic):

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view.findViewById(R.id.picture).setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.info).setOnClickListener(this);
    mTextureView =  view.findViewById(R.id.texture);

    final SurfaceView surfaceView =  view.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    SurfaceHolder mHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();


    mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    mHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot draw onto the canvas as it's null");
            } else {
                int w = canvas.getWidth();
                int h = canvas.getHeight();
                int outerFillColor = 0x33000000;
                float radius = 10.0f;

                RectF rect = new RectF(100, 100, w - 100, h - 100);
// first create an off-screen bitmap and its canvas
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, 
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                }
                Canvas auxCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

// then fill the bitmap with the desired outside color

                Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG);
                paint.setColor(outerFillColor);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                auxCanvas.drawPaint(paint);
// then punch a transparent hole in the shape of the rect
                paint.setXfermode(new 
 PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                auxCanvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);

// then draw the white rect border (being sure to get rid of the xfer 
 mode!)
                paint.setXfermode(null);
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                auxCanvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);


// finally, draw the whole thing to the original canvas
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link..
In this section image captures in onClick event. You can capture image without click by placing the capture code where you want

> [Show rectangle in camera preview and crop image within it using android camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044802/show-rectangle-in-camera-preview-and-crop-image-within-it-using-android-camera2/50905582#50905582)

Comment: How to write the capture code which i am struggling also where to place it . Should i place it inside the onClick() ?

Comment: Ok, i thought You need code for auto capturing image inside a rectangle

Comment: i need a code where i can auto capture the moment an object comes inside rectangle overlay after touching the four corners of the overlay

Comment: Follow the link and this line is for capturingimage : camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);

Comment: i could not understand. since i am using Camera2 api and the part of the code you gave me uses Camera api.